# Python3 Argparse Trying to read a file and count the letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, argparse

I've made a function that opens a textfile and counts the letters, it looks like this:

```
def count_letters(fname):
    lettercounter = 0
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        letters = []
        Scharacters = [",", ".", " "]
        for letter in f.read():
            if letter not in Scharacters:
                lettercounter += 1

        return lettercounter
```

However when I try to run it like this:

```
if opts["known_args"]["commands"] == "letters":
        funk.count_letters(opts["known_args"])
```

It returns an error:

> ```
> line 35, in count_letters
>     with open(fname, "r") as f:
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict
> ```

Could someone please explain what is happening? It is supposed to make a list and then return the number of letters inside, so I am not sure where the dict came from...Am I opening the file in a wrong way, since it points to the line where the file is opened?

Comment: Why not just increment a counter? `if letter not in Scharacters: lettercounter += 1`. No need to keep a list of letters at all here.

Comment: Fair point, I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a dictionary object (your `opts["known_args"]` variable) to the `fname` parameter of your `count_letters()` method. That parameter is then being used for `open(fname, "r")`, which expects a filename string (or os.path).

For example something like this would work:

```
if opts["known_args"]["commands"] == "letters":
    funk.count_letters("/path/to/file")
```

Comment: I think it passes the entire dictionary with the known arguments: opts: {'known_args': {'silent': 'False', 'verbose': 'False', 'filename': 'phil.txt', 'commands': 'letters'}, 'unknown_args': []} <class 'dict'>.                 
 Do I then need to move it to unknown arguments instead?

Comment: You have `opts["known_args"]["filename"]` in this dictionary, so you could pass this to your `count_letters()` method?

Comment: Well it's cleared the error, so does the file you're trying to open ("phil.txt") exist?

Comment: Yeah, it is located on my desktop, so it is in the same "folder" as the other files that are being used.